# Getting error while compiling app with Py2app on Python 2.7 (raise ImportError("No module named " + qname))

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, py2app

I am on Mac 10.14, Python 2.7 (installed from binary downloaded from https://www.python.org), running from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python.
I have py2app installed, latest version, but when trying to compile apps, I get the below error:

```
MacBook-Pro:Audio_Export_App kevin$ sudo python setup.py py2app
Password:
running py2app
creating /Users/kevin/python_scripts/Audio_Export_App/build
creating /Users/kevin/python_scripts/Audio_Export_App/build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64
creating /Users/kevin/python_scripts/Audio_Export_App/build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python2.7-standalone
creating /Users/kevin/python_scripts/Audio_Export_App/build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app
creating /Users/kevin/python_scripts/Audio_Export_App/build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/collect
creating /Users/kevin/python_scripts/Audio_Export_App/build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/temp
creating /Users/kevin/python_scripts/Audio_Export_App/dist
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/lib-dynload
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/Frameworks
--- Skipping recipe pyside ---
*** using recipe: subprocess ***
--- Skipping recipe pyside ---
*** using recipe: virtualenv ***
--- Skipping recipe pyside ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
*** using recipe: importlib ***
--- Skipping recipe pyside ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
*** using recipe: re ***
--- Skipping recipe pyside ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 23, in <module>
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 140, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 838, in run
    self._run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1053, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1150, in run_normal
    self.process_recipes(mf, filters, flatpackages, loader_files)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1007, in process_recipes
    rval = check(self, mf)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/recipes/six.py", line 113, in check
    mf.import_hook(nm, m)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1082, in import_hook
    q, tail = self._find_head_package(parent, name, level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1182, in _find_head_package
    raise ImportError("No module named " + qname)
ImportError: No module named gdbm
```

I cannot find what is wrong here. Any suggestions please?

Comment: There's probably no module named `gdbm`? I honesly have no idea what that is or if it's supposed to be installed in this context. Try `pip install gdbm`?

Comment: pip install gdbm was the first thing I tried, but "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gdbm (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for gdbm"

Answer (score 1):

At this time (Dec 2018) there is some problem with the version of Py2app for Python 2.7.
I managed to get it working by using older version:

```
py2app==0.16
```

EDIT 21-12-2018: the problem turns out to be that support for `six.moves` was added in 0.17. I reported the problem: https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app/issues/257/sixmoves-recipe-broke-something

Comment: Can you clarify the fix? How do you get/run the the older version of py2app?

Comment: You run `pip install py2app==0.16`, this will remove the currently installed `py2app` and replace it with the specific version.